# Ответ systemd сервиса о его состоянииях

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bash, systemd

Есть приложение, написанное на c++/qt. Оно запущено как сервис в systemd.
Мне необходимо получить информацию о состоянии приложения, некий healthcheck. Как это возможно реализовать?
Допустим, запущен сервис testworker.service. И, например, командой bash:

```
testworker -statuscheck
```

сервис возвращал мне код некого состояния.
Логику состояния сервиса я могу описать сам, интересует как реализовать ответ средствами qt.

Comment: Средства Qt тут ни при чём, стандартный способ возвратить статус - это return из main либо значение переданное в `std::exit`. Ещё, если у вас systemd, можно использовать системный вызов [`sd_notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html#)

Comment: Но ведь мне необходимо вернуть состояние рабочей программы. Например как при выводе команды -help в приложении linux

Comment: Так в чём проблема-то? Вы же говорили, что можете логику состояния написать сами...

Comment: тут  rpc надо городить)